# onChange event - nodes can't be found

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, onchange

Trying to get this onChange event to pass.
This is what I tried at the moment but I get the following error :
  **Method “simulate” is meant to be run on 1 node. 0 found instead.**

file.test.js

```
it("should call onChange events on Settings-input-radio ", () => {
 baseProps.onChange.mockClear();
 wrapper.setProps({
  });
 wrapper.setState({
    IsSystem:true
    });
 wrapper.update() 
 wrapper.find('input[id="radio-input-true"]').simulate('change')
 expect(wrapper.state('isSystem')).toBeTrue
```

I added an Id on the file to test it out, not sure if its needed
Here is file.js

Render

```
<div className='settings-input-radio'>
  <input type='radio' className='settings-radio' id='radio-input-true'
   checked={this.state.isSystem} onChange={(e) => {this.updateJSON('System', true); this.setState({isSystem: true})}}/>
     Yes
  <input type='radio' className='settings-radio'
   checked={!this.state.isSystem} onChange={(e) => {this.updateJSON('System', false); this.setState({isSystem: false})}}/>
     No
</div>
```

Method:

```
updateJSON = (name, value) => {
 let json = this.props.selectedFormJSON;
 json[name] = value
 this.props.updateSelectedFormJSON(json);
}
```

Comment: 0

 
If I try to run by type or class Name, nodes are found
Id cannot be inserted in this case due to this message: is changing a controlled input of type radio to be uncontrolled. Input elements should not switch from controlled to uncontrolled (or vice versa)

Answer (score 0):

Able to test onChange event, 
forgot to set one of the props= true. As a result, test was able to find more nodes